# Performance issue when show RichTextBlock inside ScrollViewer

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, scrollviewer, richtextblock

I have a RichTextBlock in a ScrollViewer, when the content of the RichTextBlock is too long, there will be very serious performance issue. FYI, the actual height of the RichTextBlock is about 580000. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Note that it's 5 years since the question, but I can confirm that any substantially large amount of text in the `RichTextBlock` causes performance degradation. Rough estimate is that (based on the hardware) between 1'000 and 10'000 small and simple paragraphs can trigger a significant scroll staggering. I've got a proof-of-concept virtualization code, but didn't have to use it in a real life project as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, RichTextBox should support Virtualization out of the box.  However if you still face performace issue you should consider for third-party vendors like Telerik, Syncfusion or DevExpress.